# Trouble with Dijkstra , finding all minimum paths

Tags: c++, dijkstra

We have a problem here, we're trying to find all the shortest paths in graph from one node to another. We have already implemented dijkstra but we really dont know how to find them all.

Do we have to use BFS?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

typedef pair <int, int> dist_node;
typedef pair <int, int> edge;
const int MAXN = 10000;
const int INF = 1 << 30;
vector <edge> g[MAXN];
int d[MAXN];
int p[MAXN];

int dijkstra(int s, int n,int t){
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i){
        d[i] = INF;  p[i] = -1;
    }
    priority_queue < dist_node, vector <dist_node>,greater<dist_node> > q;
    d[s] = 0;
    q.push(dist_node(0, s));
    while (!q.empty()){
        int dist = q.top().first;
        int cur = q.top().second;
        q.pop();
        if (dist > d[cur]) continue;
        for (int i = 0; i < g[cur].size(); ++i){
            int next = g[cur][i].first;
            int w_extra = g[cur][i].second;
            if (d[cur] + w_extra < d[next]){
                d[next] = d[cur] + w_extra;
                p[next] = cur;
                q.push(dist_node(d[next], next));
            }
        }
    }
    return d[t];
}

vector <int> findpath (int t){
    vector <int> path;
    int cur=t;
    while(cur != -1){
        path.push_back(cur);
        cur = p[cur];
    }
    reverse(path.begin(), path.end());
    return path;
}
```

This is our code, we believe we have to modify it but we really don't know where.

Comment: homework question? :(

Comment: spoj problem , proving myself

Comment: I think Dijkstra can only solve single-source shortest path problems, and of you want to do it for all vertices you need something like [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)

Comment: yeap, but I need to find all possible shortest paths, from a single source to an specific node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are only saving/retrieving one of the shortest paths that you happen to find. Consider this example:

```
4 nodes
0 -> 1
0 -> 2
1 -> 3
2 -> 3
```

It becomes clear that you cannot have a single `p[]` value for each position, as in fact the 4th node (`3`) has 2 previous valid nodes: `1` and `2`.

You could thus replace it with a `vector<int> p[MAXN];` and work as follows:

```
if (d[cur] + w_extra < d[next]){
    d[next] = d[cur] + w_extra;
    p[next].clear();
    p[next].push_back(cur);
    q.push(dist_node(d[next], next));
}
else if(d[cur] + w_extra == d[next]){
    p[next].push_back(cur); // a new shortest way of hitting this same node
}
```

You will also need to update your `findpath()` function as it will need to deal with "branches" resulting in several multiple paths, possibly an exponentially huge amount of paths depending on the graph. If you just need to print the paths, you could do something like this:

```
int answer[MAXN];

void findpath (int t, int depth){
    if(t == -1){ // we reached the initial node of one shortest path
        for(int i = depth-1; i >= 0; --i){
            printf("%d ", answer[i]);
        }
        printf("%d\n", last_node); // the target end node of the search
        return;
    }
    for(int i = p[t].size()-1; i >= 0; --i){
        answer[depth] = p[t][i];
        findpath(p[t][i], depth+1);
    }
}
```

Note you'll need to do `p[s].push_back(-1)` at the beginning of your dijkstra, besides clearing this vector array between cases.

Comment: instead of printing them, you could save them at that time. You would need a global structure such as `vector< vector<int> > paths;` and you would populate each path into a vector<int>, and then push this vector inside your `paths` vector of vectors. Beware the actual amount of paths may be so big you will not have enough memory to store all of them, and instead of saving, you would need to call whichever function needs to use the paths, each time a new path was found (that is, when `t == -1` inside `findpath()`).